# Changing my 'seed' file - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have already seeded my user into the database, but now I would like to change one of those fields. It seems, like the migrations, I cannot just edit the file and run `rake db:seed`. That doesnt seem to change anything. How do I edit something I have already seeded in? Thanks!

Comment: Change your seed file, open a console and change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the console to change data you've already seeded, or is otherwise already in your database.  If it's a lot of data you need to change you can write a migration to make changes to the data, as well as the table structure.

To use the console

```
rails c
> u = User.last
> u.first_name = "BoyGeorge"
> u.save
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know how I could do this on `Heroku`? Because that seeded `user` has changed also...

Comment: Heroku has it's own console accessed with the "run" exec. You get to it with  `heroku run console`, similar to the rake commands, `heroku run rake db:migrate` or `heroku run rake routes`